# Strange code generated by llvm for goto *(void *)&&label

Tags: compilation, clang, compiler-optimization

I noticed that clang (clang-1400.0.29.202) generates different code for `goto *&&label` and `goto *(void*)&&label`: in the former case it emits the (expected) jump to the label, but in the latter, it loads the label address in a register and then makes an indirect jump through the register.

Here is the minimal reproducer:

```
void run(long *x) {
    if (x[2]) {
#if X
        goto *&&end;
#else
        goto *(void*)&&end;
#endif
    }
beg:
    x[4] = x[2] ? (long)&&beg : (long)&&end;
end:
    if (x[3])
        goto *(void *)x[4];
}
```

and then:

```
diff -u <(cc -DX=1 -O3 -S -o- run.c) <(cc -DX=0 -O3 -S -o- run.c) 
--- /dev/fd/63  2022-11-04 15:05:34.000000000 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/62  2022-11-04 15:05:34.000000000 -0700
@@ -11,25 +11,24 @@
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    16(%rdi), %rax
+   leaq    Ltmp0(%rip), %rcx       <---- Load the label into rcx.
    testq   %rax, %rax
-   jne LBB0_2
-Ltmp0:                                  ## Block address taken
+   je  LBB0_1
+## %bb.5:
+   jmpq    *%rcx                    <---- Indirect jump to the label.
+Ltmp1:                                  ## Block address taken
 LBB0_1:
    testq   %rax, %rax
-   leaq    Ltmp1(%rip), %rcx
-   leaq    Ltmp0(%rip), %rdx
+   leaq    Ltmp1(%rip), %rdx
    cmoveq  %rcx, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 32(%rdi)
-LBB0_2:
-   movq    24(%rdi), %rcx
-   .p2align    4, 0x90
-Ltmp1:                                  ## Block address taken
-LBB0_3:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
-   testq   %rcx, %rcx
-   je  LBB0_5
-## %bb.4:                               ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_3 Depth=1
+Ltmp0:                                  ## Block address taken
+LBB0_2:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
+   cmpq    $0, 24(%rdi)
+   je  LBB0_4
+## %bb.3:                               ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_2 Depth=1
    jmpq    *32(%rdi)
-LBB0_5:
+LBB0_4:
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

It still reproduces if `void *` is replaced with something like `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`. gcc, on the other hand, emits direct jumps in both cases. I tried the latest clang on godbolt, the result is the same.

What could be the reason for this indirect jump?

Comment: Looks like a missed optimization; like common-subexpression-elimination run amok; it already needs the target address in a register for `x[4] = x[2] ? (long)&&beg : (long)&&end;`, but chooses to do it early and jump-to-register instead of a relative jump. 
 https://godbolt.org/z/j7Te74KPM shows the two builds side-by-side; this diff is unfortunately not very comprehensible if you haven't seen just one of them in isolation and haven't spend a long time studying the C logic.

Comment: When a different label is used in the ternary expression (https://godbolt.org/z/Wdebq1zcG) it still jumps through the register, so something else ("cast is not an lvalue"?) broke the delicate balance of optimiser's mind.